# Apply fixed CSS declarations to other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The basic premise is that we have a CSS string saved in a database as customization for a website.

I cannot change this string, and need colors applied to different elements than they were already designed for.

For the sake of this question, let’s simplify the CSS string down to:

```
.navbar-item:not(.navbar-brand):not(.active){
    background-color:#2795EE;
}

.navbar-item:not(.navbar-brand):not(.active):hover{
    background-color:#f18c16;
    color:inherit;
}
```

I have changed the structure of the subnavigation, and now have `.navbar-item` applied to the parent `.navbar`, as well as all items within it. This is because I need the `background-color` from the `.navbar-item` applied to the navbar.

The issue is, when I apply .navbar-item to the `navbar`, as well as to each `li` within the navbar, the background of the navbar highlights on hover of the child `li` elements.

This jsfiddle almost certainly demonstrates the issue better than I can explain: https://jsfiddle.net/dbrotuwt/1/.

I’d like to be able to create a new class, and apply the style declared in `.navbar-item` to it like:

```
.new-class{
    .navbar-item;
}
```

But from my research I know that this is not possible without using less or similar, which I cannot do.

I think it’s possible to do using jQuery, but I’d prefer a pure CSS solution if possible.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the same as `.new-class .navbar-item`? That's how it'd be compiled from LESS.

Comment: Yes it would, but I'd like to apply the styles declared in .navbar-item to new class, rather than include .navbar-item as a CSS class on the HTML element.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're asking for isn't possible with plain CSS. What would work is if you stored only the values for the styling on your server, then used those as variables in SASS/Less to compile a new stylesheet (on the server) when they get updated. This gives you a lot more control over what can/can't be styled as well.

Comment: Okay - thank you. I'll write something in jQuery. Hindsight is a wonderful thing, eh?